# Feature Request: Enumeration of issues with Workspace Trust "Do you trust the authors of the file in this folder?"

Tags: task, load, project, workspace, trust

When loading a project in VSCode for the first time, I get the "Do you trust the authors of the files in this folder" but it won't inform me about the specifics for what I need to be concerned about.
I think it would be more helpful to list out the issues as VSCode has obviously detected already these issues.

I had to go through the documentation on Workspace Trust and inspect my .vscode and other files per the documentation which took considerable time to understand the documentation and follow the instruction, and still may have missed some actions.
I'm expecting VSCode to tell me specifically what it is complaining about to identify if it's an issue or not.